# data from parse won't print on my app

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I've been following a tutorial that works with *Swift* and *Parse*, when I run the app I should get a table with 10 names (of type `String`) on the `TableView`, however it does not show any of the name and I get this is the error in Xcode:

> 2015-11-09 15:37:05.223 Paws[12838:1116345] [Error]: unauthorized
>   (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out I had written in the wrong Application ID in my appDelegate file, and thats why the connection wasn't working between my view and parse.

Sorry I did not see it before I posted this.